# Update loop and buttons in cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, game-physics, game-loop

I have a simple lunar lander game.
I compute positions and everything by integration - e.g. each turn I take vectors and combine them and then apply resulting vector to my lander.

Here comes the question, I have a button that I want to use for thrust.
How do I check if it is on during update method? I guess i will have some BOOL flag that gets set to YES when the button is pressed, but when do i set it to NO?
Some practical implementation would be great.
I use cocos2d-iphone and iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the pseudo code goes as follows:

1. We shall not use Buttons (aka CCMenuItem), since they provide callbacks only on touch up events. We want touch down, touch exit/entered, touch ended.
2. In your `CCScene` that you are displaying, either add a new child that is a subclass of `CCLayer` or even use one of the `CCLayer`s already present in the `CCScene`.
3. In the init of your `CClayer` subclass, set `isTouchEnabled` to `YES`.
4. Implement the usual methods:

```
    - (void)ccTouchesBegan:...
    - (void)ccTouchesMoved:...
    - (void)ccTouchesEnded:...
    - (void)ccTouchesCancelled:...
```

Finally, do your magic in these methods.

- Get the touch location
- Check using `CGRectContainsPoint` whether the touch is within the thrust area.
- and so on, and so forth...